# I need some basic introduction to limits

Tags: calculus, limits, arithmetic

So, I know you can obviously cut out a value if it is multiplying and dividing something at the same time, right? Like:

$$\frac{4h-2xh-h^2}{h} = \frac{h(4-2x-h)}{h} = 4-2x-h$$

But then I saw this same equation on an explample about finding the differential of a function
$$f(x)=4x-x^2$$

Which is given by
$$\frac{(4(x+h)-(x+h)^2)-(4x-x^2)}{h}=\frac{4x+4h-x^2-2xh-h^2-4x+x^2}{h}$$
$$=\frac{4h-2xh-h^2}{h} = \frac{h(4-2x-h)}{h} = 4-2x$$

For some reason the other $h$ on the numerator got cut out too, and I know it has something to do with an implied limit as $h\to0$ on this formula for finding the differential, but I don't have a clue on what is that mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative is that expression as $h$ approaches zero.  That's how the other $h$ got "cut out" (set to $0$) at the very end:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} (4 - 2x - h) = 4 - 2x - 0 = 4 - 2x.$$

Comment: As someone with really low knowledge on maths, does that basically mean you can always cut out something if it tends to 0?

Comment: "Cutting out" in this case really means "setting $h$ to $0$" but things get a little trickier if by setting $h$ to $0$ you get zero in the denominator.  If you've heard that you "can't divide by zero," well, calculus is the time when you start to learn more about what that means.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit more.  Taking the limit in this case *amounts to* setting $h$ to $0$, because $\lim_{h \to 0} h = 0.$

Comment: Oh, ok, so I need to make those algebraic manipulations in order to get the $h$ out of the denominator cause I can't set it to $0$ if it's dividing something (or if it's anywhere else where $0$ is not acceptable) then I'm free to set it to $0$ and get rid of this variable.

Comment: In this case, you can get $h$ out of the denominator.  But in some cases, you can't!  And what's more, it sometimes depends on *which direction* you approach from.  How about $\lim_{h \to 0} 1/h$?  This is $+\infty$ if you approach zero from the positive side, and $-\infty$ if you approach zero from the negative side. Fun stuff. :)

Comment: I didn't get it but I'll get there some day xD I better just hope I can always get rid of it in the questions on my upcoming exam.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

You are right in the last equation $\frac{4h-2xh-h^2}{h} = \frac{h(4-2x-h)}{h} = 4-2x$, when it must be $\frac{h(4-2x-h)}{h} \rightarrow 4-2x$ as $h \rightarrow 0$.

In the beginning they used the definition of the derivative:
$$
f'(x) = \lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}.
$$

They calculated $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ first, and after calculating they took the limit.

Answer (score 2):

If what you've written is a verbatim quote, then the source is incorrect. They are being sloppy with their limits.

If $f(x)=4x-x^2,$ then for any non-zero $h,$ we can say that $$\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=4-2x-h,$$ as you determined. What this means is that $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h$ and $4-2x-h$ are exactly the same for any non-zero $h.$ As we let $h$ get closer and closer to $0$, then, both expressions tend toward $4-2x,$ so we can say that $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\to 0}[4-2x-h]=4-2x.$$ That would be a correct statement, and is what they are trying to say.